# Kubernetes: pods network isolation

Tags: kubernetes

We need to know about `pods` network isolation.

Is there a possibility to access `one pod` from `another one` in cluster? Maybe by `namespace` dividing?

We also need `pod`'s membership in local networks, which are not accessible from outside.


Any plans? Is it will be soon?

Answer (score 1):

In a standard Kubernetes installation, all pods (even across namespaces) share a flat IP space and can all communicate with each other.

To get isolation, you'll need to customize your install to prevent cross namespace communication. One way to do this is to use OpenContrail. They recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.opencontrail.org/kube-o-contrail-get-your-hands-dirty-with-kubernetes-and-opencontrail/) describing an example deployment using the Guestbook from the Kubernetes repository.